# ERROR ON INSTALLING DEPENDENCIES ON NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

How do i can fix this issue?

i just run `npm install --save`
and i got this

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Your platform is not supported. As much as I am aware fsevents doesn't work with windows. Try Linux subsystem in Windows. I have not tried it. Logically it should work. But if it doesn't, expect it not to work

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a warning and not an error.
You can fix it by installing it by force like this :

```
npm install -f
```